# Reuse VueJS components outside solution

Tags: vue.js, components, reusability

I have 2 VueJs solutions which I made with VS2019:

**Solution A**

```
components
   component1.vue
   component2.vue
```

**Solution B**

```
components
   component3.vue
   component4.vue
```

I need to reuse the SolutionA components in the SolutionB, is there a way to do it without publish the SolutionA in `npm`?

Thanks!

Comment: why you don't import it locally?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

- Use `npm link` to reference the SolutionA in the SolutionB;
- Add SolutionA in devDependecies of the SolutionB package.json;
- Then simply import the component1.vue in the component3.vue